# How to add mapped element to state onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the `render` of my App.js component I have table that displays items mapped from an array. The array has objects with string values for `code` and `mod_name`

```
...
{modules.map((mod, i) => (
  <tr>
    <td> {mod.code} </td> 
    <td> {mod.mod_name} </td>
    <td>
      <Input type="button" onClick={this.onCheckbox(mod.code)} /> 
    </td>
  </tr>
))}
...
```

The `Input` is a checkbox, and I want to add/remove the `mod.code` for the row based on if the checkbox is marked.

Currently, my `onCheckbox` method looks like this:

```
onCheckbox (data) {
  const arr = this.state.selected;
  if(arr.includes(data)) {
    const index = arr.indexOff(data)
    if(index > -1) {
      arr.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({selected: arr})
    }
  } else {
    this.setState({selected: [...this.state.selected: arr]})
  }
}
```

However, I get an error:
`Unhandled Rejection (Error): Maximum update depth exceeded.`

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
{modules.map((mod, i) => (
  <tr>
    <td> {mod.code} </td> 
    <td> {mod.mod_name} </td>
    <td>
      <Input type="button" onClick={this.onCheckbox(mod.code)} /> 
      <button onClick={()=> deleteHandle(mod)}>Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
))}
```

function `deleteHandle`

```
function deleteHandle=item=>{
 let filtered = this.state.modules.filter(module=>module.id!==item.id);
 this.setState({modules: filtered})
}
```

Like i created for button you can change as per your objective/requirement.